# Keep same project source for development and production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, github

I have an general query about maintaining our project. Our project has some code changes between development source and production source. That is production source has live database configuration in web config, and payment checkout mode set to production in some class files. But in development source these are set to testing environment. Other than those both the development and production has same codes. Because of having difference between development and production source, we have to keep these source separately and work on two sources to publish any changes. We are frequently doing any features and bug fixes and publish the changes immediately. So we couldn’t follow [Gitflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) model (development and master). But [Github](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) model will suit for our case because of having immediate publish after feature or bug fixes done.

The problem is Github model says to maintain master source alone. But in our case master source connected to production database, so taking branch from master also connect to production. We need our development should be done with testing configuration. How can we maintain production and testing configuration in master branch itself and switching some configuration leads to connect to testing or production. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks,
Karthik.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, Your problem really is about how to keep test config and production config seperate.

If I am right, then here is my two cents.

Say if all your config is in web.config, why not use the config transformation, where you save your test config to git (master) and 
use transform to change it to production config when publishing.

In essense, it is just creating another `Web.{build profile name}.config` where when you publish in that build profile, your web.config will be transorm

more detail check
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations

Answer (score 0):

1. For configuration changes use web config transformations. You can run those [enable transformations on build with Visual Studio](https://gist.github.com/EdCharbeneau/9135216)
2. Use dependency injection for mocking/faking implementations. You can set some key in web.config (the value is going to be set in web config transformations) which will determine whether to use fake implementation or the real-one